# Programatically constraint doesn't work inside UICollectionViewCell Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I tried to make a programatically view inside `UICollectionViewCell`, and I think it will be wise to put the "programatically view code" inside `UICollectionViewCell`.

So here is my code:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        let view = UIView()
        view.frame = CGRect.zero
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        self.contentView.addSubview(view)
        self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0),
            view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
            view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 25),
            view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 25),
            ])

        self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

I was wondering why the auto layout does not work, instead if I use manual `CGRect`,  the view did appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This Solve it just needs to set
>   `view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` 
>    not The contenView

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    let view = UIView()
    view.frame = CGRect.zero
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black


    self.contentView.addSubview(view)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0),
        view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
        view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 25),
        view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 25),
        ])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change
`self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`
to:
`view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

You'd like to turn off the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` of your `view` since we want to apply `autolayout` to it.

Answer (score 1):

**First:** You should not call `layoutIfNeeded` method, the auto layout cycle will do this for you after you change the rules (constraints)

**Second:** You should set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property to `false` for the view that will be layed out, so you should not do this

```
self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

but you should do this

```
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

> That's because autoresizing mask constraints are applied to your `view` with constraints that you've set. This may and probably will cause constraints break.

If this won't help then provide console output with autolayout errors.

Comment: noted. the thing that `layoutIfNeeded` is pretty crucial , thanks man